# What does “T-securities” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across the word *T-securities* in the following comment of one of readers to the article of the Time magazine (April 19) titled “Don’t worry about the U.S. debt. - The world too vested in America to quit now.”

> The debt growth could end tomorrow, if the government simply stopped creating *T-securities*. Why would a government with the unlimited ability to create dollars, need to borrow those dollars? Michael, please, try to learn and understand Monetary Sovereignty.

As far as I’ve checked, no dictionary including online dictionaries has entry of the word *T-securities*.
Although I guess it means "U.S. Treasury securities," I’m not sure. Can anyone tell me what it presents for? Is this a new abbreviation? As I said, I cant find this word in any dictinaries.

Comment: it most definitely *is* Treasury securities. http://business.rediff.com/slide-show/2010/may/24/slide-show-1-worlds-largest-holders-of-us-treasury-bonds.htm This article starts off with "US Treasury securities" and later just abbreviates to T-Securities.

Comment: It's not really an "abbreviation for" "Treasury securities".  As you yourself explain in your answer: It is a **play on** (if you will) the three incredibly common phrases tbills, tnotes and tbonds.  Just as you say, it's an "umbrella" term that has spring up, for when you wish to refer to, somewhat confusingly, "tbills, tnotes and tbonds" all at once. The literal answer to "What does T-securities mean?" is: "it means T-bills, T-notes and T-bonds".  (Indeed, banker etc. sometimes just say "Ts" ("tees") to mean the same trio of things.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that the US Treasury Securities actually comprise of

- [Treasury Bills](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/products/prod_tbills_glance.htm) (or T-bills)
- [Treasury Notes](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/products/prod_tnotes_glance.htm) (or T-Notes)
- [Treasury Bonds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Treasury_security#Treasury_bond) (or T-Bonds)

this seems to be the blanket umbrella term, and hence the abbreviation **T-securities**

Answer (score 4):

Undoubtedly T-securities is an abbreviation of Treasury securities, given the context of the comment, but it is not a widely used convention.  I would characterize it as a idiosyncratic usage.  However, it is similar to the term *T-bills*, which is a widely used term for *Treasury bills*.  T-bills are Treasury debt instruments having a maturity of one year or less, and thus are a subset of all Treasury securities.